# Knockout foreach check if value of field is same as previous value in array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using a foreach in Knockout to view data, and for each record I want to check if the Date field is the same as the Date field of the previous record, if so not show it, otherwise show it.

Ideally I want a layout something like this :

```
12/12/2014    
----------
Record 1   -  Field 1    Field 2   Field 3
Record 2   -  Field 1    Field 2   Field 3


14/12/2014
----------
Record 3   -  Field 1    Field 2   Field 3
```

Here is my current foreach loop, what syntax would I use to be able to compare a field value to the previous field value in the array?  I have googled around but not found any examples of variables being used within Knockout foreach loops.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: fixture.fixtures">
            <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: FixtureDate"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: FixtureId"></td>
                    <td><img data-bind="attr:{src: HomeBadge}" /></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: HomeName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: HomeScore"></td>
                    <td style="width:15px;"></td>
                    <td><img data-bind="attr:{src: AwayBadge}" /></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: AwayName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: AwayScore"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Comment: You can't compare in this foreach loop the way you're thinking. What you should do is have your fixture.fixtures array include only the fields you want. So I would create logic in your Model to create this array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a Computed Observable to do the filtering, and bind your tbody to that. Any conditionals should be controlled by your model, not the view. Something like:

```
var deduped = ko.pureComputed(function () {
    var result = [];
    var originalValues = fixture.fixtures();
    for (var i=1; i<originalValues.length; ++i) {
        if (originalValues[i].date != originalValues[i-1].date) {
            result.push(orignalValues[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
});
```

Actually, it looks like you want to have a couple of nested foreach loops: the outer one for dates, and the inner one for the record/field data. Write your HTML as if your data were convenient to present, and then use Computed Observables to make it that way.

Comment: Could you give a code example to explain what you mean? I am not sure how I would use Computed Observables in this context.